# How to use the externals in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
externals: {
      'react-redux': 'ReactRedux',
      'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
      'react': 'React',
      'jquery': 'jQuery',
      'redux': 'Redux'
  }
```

Comment: what are wanting to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Webpack Docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html):

> `externals` allows you to specify dependencies for your library that are not resolved by webpack, but become dependencies of the output. This means they are imported from the environment during runtime.

Also an example of recommended config from there:

```
{
    output: {
        // export itself to a global var
        libraryTarget: "var",
        // name of the global var: "Foo"
        library: "Foo"
    },
    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this

```
externals: [{
  'react': {
    root: 'React',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    commonjs: 'react',
    amd: 'react'
  }
}, {
  'react-dom': {
    root: 'ReactDOM',
    commonjs2: 'react-dom',
    commonjs: 'react-dom',
    amd: 'react-dom'
  }
}]
```

in my open sourced component [react-lazy](https://github.com/jonathanobino/react-lazy), take a look at the repo for the full webpack config file.